# Extracting the declartion line of each varible from external C++ source code

Tags: python, c++, parsing

Is there a way to parse a c++ source code , and get for each variable the line it was declared in ? 
You can ignore global variables and functions parameters , but it must handle pointers and any user defined objects .

something like:

```
int main(){
    int x = 5,y = 6;
    Car c1(1,2,3);
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

x,2

y,2

c1,3

It is preferred if it can be done in c++ or python , but it is ok if it can be done in any other language .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Looks like a job for an IDE, or for regex if an IDE is not an option. You have to be clearer on what type of declarations you want to find, though.

Comment: Try clang-ast maybe.

Comment: added example to make it clear for you , I need such output file to be used by another program

Comment: Of course there is a way to do it :)

Comment: There may even be *static analysis* tools that can generate *cross reference* tables that show where the variables are declared.  See "ctags" and "etags".

Comment: Thanks everyone (especially @MarcinZdunek) , clang was the best choice for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a viciously hard language to parse correctly.  The declaration syntax is bad enough, but preprocessor macros provide another whole heap of pain on top.

The most robust way to do it, is to use something like `ctags` or build a code analysis tool using clang.

Other than that, you could try writing a regex (except now you have two problems).

Comment: Thanks , clang was helpful =D